# How to Properly Update TextViews in the UI in Android?

Tags: android, while-loop

I am trying update text views while this loop is processing. Here is my code that I am using for this activity.

```
public class StartDayActivity extends Activity {
Data data_;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startdayscreen);            


    Thread seperationTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            int seperationTimer = 5000;
            int weatherAffect = 0;
            int randomEventAffect = 0;
            int locationTotalAvailable = 10;
            //int servingTime = 3000;
            int totalAvailableCustomers = (weatherAffect + randomEventAffect + locationTotalAvailable);
            int dayTimer = (totalAvailableCustomers * seperationTimer);
            int seperationTimerDay = 0;
            int lemonadeSold = 11;
            int totalDrinksSold = 0;
            int pitcherSize = 12;
            int totalLemonsUsed= 0;
            int totalIceUsed =0;
            int totalSugarUsed = 0;
            int totalCupsUsed = 0;
            double drinkPrice = 0.80;

            try{                    
                while(seperationTimerDay < dayTimer){  
                    sleep(seperationTimer);
                    seperationTimerDay = seperationTimerDay + seperationTimer;
                    lemonadeSold = lemonadeSold + 1;
                    totalDrinksSold += 1;
                    data_.cups_ -= 1;
                    totalIceUsed += 2;

                    if(lemonadeSold == pitcherSize){
                        lemonadeSold = 0;
                        data_.lemons_ -= 4;
                        data_.sugar_ -= 2;  
                        totalSugarUsed +=2;
                        totalLemonsUsed +=4;                            
                    }
                    if(data_.lemons_ == 0 || data_.ice_ == 0 || data_.sugar_ ==0 || data_.cups_ == 0){
                        break;
                    }

                    updateView();
                    Log.d("TAG", "for each : " + data_.ice_);
                    //calcMarketing();
                }

                    data_.day_gross_profit_ = (totalDrinksSold * drinkPrice);
                    data_.cash_ += (totalDrinksSold * drinkPrice);
                Intent i = new Intent("com.game.lemonade.PLAYSCREEN");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            finally{
                finish();
            }

        }
    };
    seperationTimer.start();
}   

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    data_ = getData();

}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    data_ = getData();
    //refreshDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    saveData();
    //refreshDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //refreshDisplay();
}

private Data getData() {
    GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
    player_data.open();
    Data game_state = new Data(player_data.getGameString());
    player_data.close();
    return game_state;
  }

private void saveData() {
    GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
    player_data.open();
    player_data.setGameString(data_.SerializeGame());
    player_data.close();

}
private void updateView(){
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lemonsLeftText2)).setText(
            (data_.lemons_) );
}
}
```

Is there a better way to try to do this? And how would I want to do that? I get an error when I do the `updateView()` to try to update textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access the UI using threads directly.Either use an `AsyncTask` or `Handler` for your longer thread operations which effect the UI.

Check these;

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 1):

Error message already contains answer to your question.  You can not update UI from different thread -  use `runOnUIThread()` to do this.   And for battery sake -  get reference to textView in onCreate() and reuse it.

Comment: is there a way to do this while loop and still let it sleep for a period of time without using a thread?

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to change the appearance of your `View`s from any thread that is not the main thread.

@Serdar has some great suggestions for how to handle that.

Also you should avoid calling findViewById() each time you need to call setText(). findViewById() is a fairly expensive call in terms of system resources. The fewer calls like that you make the better your app will run.

I suggest you make yourself a TextView reference and make your findViewById() call inside onCreate() and set your reference to what it returns to you. Then in your updateView() method call something like `yourTxt.setText("");`

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers have covered the answer to your question, I'll point you at this section in the documentation.

[Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

In particular the last part.

> Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> - Do not block the UI thread
> - Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Two very simple rules indeed but if you stick to them you'll avoid a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Handler` class:

Where you call:

```
    updateView();
```

replace with:

```
    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

In the handler:

```
    private Handler myHandler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what==0){
            updateView();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: for launch a new Intent you should use the same example. myhandler.sendEmptyMessage(1); and add the "else if(msg.what==1){ Intent...;}"